# How should i create a page to explain how to use my plugin in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i want to add something(i dont know what should i add editor/view or something else) to explain how to use my plugin for my plugin's users in eclipse.

This thing gotta have text, some images and a web-site link(this link send user to browser, shouldn't open in eclipse) and should open from a menu item.

What should i use for all of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have It on Github? You can have It there

Comment: Have you considered plugging in to the built-in Help system? https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_content.htm?cp=2_0_19_1_1

Comment: ...and a [_Welcome_ intro part](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_defining.htm) that refers to these help topics.

Comment: @howlger thanks but welcome intro part open every time when user open eclipse. i want to open my view just user click on the menu item.